Arangodb: No file descriptors available
After having no issues with ArangoDB3 for a couple of years, suddenly, I am encountering an AQL IO Error of the form
[HTTP 500][ERR 1305] AQL: IO error: While open a file for random read: /ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb/22850496.sst: No file descriptors available (while finalizing)
This is while performing an insert of the form
insert { id: "foo", junk: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } in bar
This occurred after running a lengthy operation populating a new database.
Looking at syslog, I see the following (timestamps, etc., elided for readability):
ERROR [fae2c] {rocksdb} RocksDB encountered a background error during a compaction operation: IO error: While open a file for random read: /ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb/22850496.sst: No file descriptors available; The database will be put in read-only mode, and subsequent write errors are likely. It is advised to shut down this instance, resolve the error offline and then restart it.
ERROR [be9ea] {rocksdb} rocksdb: [db/db_impl/db_impl_compaction_flush.cc:2922] Waiting after background compaction error: IO error: While open a file for random read: /ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb/22850496.sst: No file descriptors available, Accumulated background error counts: 1
WARNING [afa17] {engines} could not sync metadata for collection 'OpenAlex_20240502/works'
WARNING [a3d0c] {engines} background settings sync failed: IO error: While open a file for random read: /ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb/22850496.sst: No file descriptors available
WARNING [afa17] {engines} could not sync metadata for collection 'OpenAlex_20240502/publishers'

The first message above seems indicative of something but I'm not sure what.
The file in question, /ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb/22850496.sst, does not exist, which would the an obvious source of the problem but I'm not sure how to cure it.
Restarting both Arango DB and the system does not clear the problem.
There is more than enough space on the filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p1                          7.3T  4.6T  2.8T  63% /ssd1
so that's not an issue.
arangodb --version reports
Arango DB Version 0.18.2, build 3518b68, Go go1.21.5
arangosh --version reports
3.11.8

architecture: 64bit
arm: false
asan: false
assertions: false
avx: true
avx2: false
boost-version: 1.78.0
build-date: 2024-02-22 14:43:37
build-repository: refs/tags/v3.11.8 eb715d099fb
compiler: gcc [11.2.1 20220219]
coverage: false
cplusplus: 202002
curl-version: none
debug: false
endianness: little
failure-tests: false
fd-client-event-handler: poll
fd-setsize: 1024
full-version-string: ArangoDB 3.11.8 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build refs/tags/v3.11.8 eb715d099fb, VPack 0.2.1, RocksDB 7.2.0, ICU 64.2, V8 7.9.317, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
icu-version: 64.2
ipo: true
iresearch-version: 1.3.0.0
jemalloc: true
libunwind: true
license: community
maintainer-mode: false
memory-profiler: true
ndebug: true
openssl-version-compile-time: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
openssl-version-run-time: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
optimization-flags: -mfxsr -mmmx -msse -msse2 -mcx16 -msahf -mpopcnt -msse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mssse3 -mpclmul -mavx -mxsave
pic: 2
pie: 2
platform: linux
reactor-type: epoll
replication2-enabled: false
rocksdb-version: 7.2.0
server-version: 3.11.8
sizeof int: 4
sizeof long: 8
sizeof void*: 8
sse42: true
tsan: false
unaligned-access: true
v8-version: 7.9.317
vpack-version: 0.2.1
zlib-version: 1.2.13

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10
Linux servername 6.5.0-28-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar 28 23:46:48 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I have tried reinstalling Arango DB to no avai. I have restarted the application from a checkpoint and it now immediately and consistently fails.
Even a simple insert as above throws the same error.
The application, written in python, is multithreaded, using the multiprocessing modules and there are 64 threads/processes all performing uploads.
I have the identical code running on another system and it happily runs to completion, so I'm puzzled as to what might be going sideways here.

I'm curious as to the reason for the downvote on this question. If I have somehow violated protocol, I'd appreciate an explanation. I believe that this question is appropriate to this forum, since I see other ArangoDB-related questions. If not, then please direct me to a better one. I looked at the Database forum but that says it's for administrators, not users. Perhaps I am mistaken. If so, please correct me and I will move the question there. If you think it's a stupid question, then please tell me why and, again, I will attempt to ask a better one.

"No file descriptors available" is the important bit. There's a system-wide limit on how many file descriptors can be open across all programs, commonly 1024. See the output of ulimit -a for the limit on your system. Something is opening too many files/sockets -- could be Arango DB, or could be something else and Arango DB is the unfortunate victim.

@JohnKugelman: That was my first though, as well, but I'm not sure how this would persist after a restart of ArangoDB or a reboot of the system. The system is otherwise relatively quiescent -- it is my desktop workstation and there is the usual melange of applications running -- web browser, text editors, etc.  I did recently update Arango from 3.10 to 3.11.  Perhaps therein lies the rub???

Check that ulimit hasn't been lowered. You can use lsof to see what processes have what file descriptors open. Check the manual for usage, it has a ton of flags.

@JohnKugelman: ulimit is set at 1024. I'm certain it hasn't been changed since I would have been the one to do it if it had. I suppose it's possible that my code is somehow leaving dangling descriptors, though it looks more like it's on the ArangoDB end.

1024 is really low, in fact it is the absolute minimum, and it is absolutely plausible that after a lengthy operation populating a new database you hit that limit. Note that it is also plausible that a restart does not solve this, because depending on the data that has previously been written (in particular WAL files), the recovery procedure needs to open a lot of files. You should simply increase the limit!

Not my downvote, but Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [ubuntu.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

@tripleee Point taken. However, in my rather lukewarm defense, when I posted the question, I thought it might've been an error of some sort in my application, perhaps related to python multithreading. It only later that I realized it was not an error in my programming but a simple matter of configuration. I stand (and sit) corrected.  Filfty lashes with a wet downvote for me.

First, I will mention that I managed to get the application to run through the expedient of deleting a couple of rather large but unused databases and rerunning the application from the start. Success! Though due more to dumb luck than intelligence as I point out below.
As the commentors indicated, I believe file descriptor limits are the culprit -- but, like a drunk under the lamp post, I was looking for my keys where the light was good, rather than where I'd actually dropped my keys.
It finally struck me this morning to carefully look at the ArangoDB startup file in /lib/systemd/system/arangodb3.service which reveals the following:
# system limits
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitNPROC=131072
TasksMax=131072

which produced a bit of an Ah Ha! moment in my dim little brain.
That led me to take a look at a backup saved before I deleted the
extraneous databases:
myobfuscatedhost:/ssd1/arangodb3/engine-rocksdb# ls -1 | grep sst | wc -l
130878

Lo and behold, those numbers are rather close.
It appears, through the use of lsof that, indeed, every file in the engine-rocksdb directory is open.
Ergo, raising the above limits should resolve the problem.
I say should since I have not as of yet fully tested my hypothesis, since as I mentioned in my opening paragraph, I temporarily resolved the problem by removing excess dataset and leaving myself enough headroom to accomplish the task at hand.
I will increase the limits in /lib/systemd/system/arangodb3.service, cross my fingers, and hope for the best.
Thanks to all who eventually managed pound the answer into my thick head.
